# "Start to feel better" vs. "Start feeling better"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Which is correct?

> He will enjoy this when he starts to feel better.

Or

> He will enjoy this when he starts feeling better.

Answer (score 1):

Either is perfectly acceptable and natural. There is no significant difference in meaning between the two.